# compare date() to string in hive query builder but not in beeline

Tags: hive

How is that,I am able to compare `date()` to string in hive query builder but not in beeline?

Example.

```
where date(timestamp) = '2019-..-..'
```

is working in query builder and not in beeline

Comment: could you try `to_date()`

Comment: to_date() is fine, my concern is, as we cannot compare date() with string, then how is this working?